# How to constrain a View with a TextInputEditText nested inside a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to constrain the height of a MaterialButton to be the same as the height of a TextInputEditText by aligning them top to top and bottom to bottom.

However, I cannot achieve that because TextInputEditText is nested inside a TextInputLayout. With this, I can only constrain the MaterialButton with TextInputLayout which gives the following :

[image]

I would like not to remove the counter (or any helper text below the TextInputEditText).

Is there any way to constrain the MaterialButton with the **nested** TextInputEditText (top to top and bottom to bottom) so that they appear with the same height ?

Here is my code:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/finish_panel">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/chat_text_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/chat_send_button"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_clear"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="200"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint="Chat">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxHeight="200dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Just to make things clear. You want the button to be in the (center) alignment of `TextInputEditText` or you want to make it the same size? Should button size grow if the `TextInputEditText` content expands?

Comment: Okay, I will edit my code. Let's say that I want them to have the same height

Comment: If the TextInputEditText should not dynamically grow in size you could define a fixed height for the TextInputEditText and the MaterialButton.

Comment: Thank you. It could be a partial solution. But I would like to make the button really constrained to the editText, so that they can have the same lengths, or be aligned with same middle line.

Answer (score 1):

*ConstraintLayout* can apply constraints only to direct children. Since the *TextInputEditText* view you want to constrain the button to is a child of the *TextInputLayout* and not a direct child of  the *ConstraintLayout*, any attempt to apply constraints between the button and the *TextInputEditText* fails.

We could set a layout listener on the *ConstraintLayout*, capture the size and location of the *TextInputEditText* and modify the button view to set its size and position. This would require special coding to make the changes and is a valid solution.

However, what if we had a reusable type of view that could reference a view embedded in a child *ViewGroup* and replicate the embedded view's size and placement as a direct child of the *ConstraintLayout*? We could then constrain the button to this new type of view and get the placement that we want.

Such a custom view could be based upon the [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) class, but it could also be built upon the [ConstraintHelper](https://cs.android.com/androidx/constraintlayout/+/main:constraintlayout/constraintlayout/src/main/java/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintHelper.java?q=constrainthelper.java&ss=androidx%2Fconstraintlayout) class which extends *View*. This class is the basis for other "helper" classes in *ConstraintLayout* such as [Group](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Group), [GuideLine](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Guideline) and others. From my perspective, *ConstraintHelper* is a good fit for the custom view.

Here is such a custom view:

**ViewSurrogate.kt**

```
class ViewSurrogate @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintHelper(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private lateinit var mContainer: ConstraintLayout
    private var mTargetId: Int = NO_ID
    private lateinit var mTargetView: View
    private var mDrawOutline = false
    private var mPaint: Paint? = null

    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.ViewSurrogate, 0, 0
        ).apply {
            try {
                mDrawOutline = getBoolean(R.styleable.ViewSurrogate_drawOutline, false)
                mTargetId = getResourceId(R.styleable.ViewSurrogate_targetView, NO_ID)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }

        if (mTargetId == NO_ID) throw InvalidTarget("app:targetId was not specified.")
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        if (this::mContainer.isInitialized) return

        mContainer = (parent as ConstraintLayout).also { container ->
            mTargetView = container.findViewById(mTargetId)
                ?: throw InvalidTarget("Can't find target view in layout.")
        }
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        if (!mDrawOutline) return

        val paint = mPaint
            ?: Paint().apply {
                style = Paint.Style.STROKE
                color = Color.RED
                strokeWidth = 10f
                pathEffect = DashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(15f, 15f, 15f, 15f), 0f)
            }
        canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), paint)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        setDimensionsFromTarget(mTargetView)
    }

    override fun updatePostLayout(container: ConstraintLayout?) {
        super.updatePostLayout(container)

        mTargetView.let { targetView ->
            val pos = getPositionInCommonAncestor(targetView)
            val lp = layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
            if (lp.marginStart != pos.x || lp.topMargin != pos.y) {
                lp.setMargins(pos.x, pos.y, 0, 0)
                requestLayout()
            } else if (width != targetView.width || height != targetView.height) {
                requestLayout()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getBaseline() = mTargetView.baseline 

    private fun getPositionInCommonAncestor(targetView: View): TargetViewOffset {
        var viewY = targetView.y
        var viewX = targetView.x
        var targetAncestor: ViewGroup? = targetView.parent as ViewGroup
        while (targetAncestor != null && targetAncestor != parent) {
            viewY += targetAncestor.y
            viewX += targetAncestor.x
            targetAncestor = targetAncestor.parent as ViewGroup
        }
        if (targetAncestor == null) {
            throw WrongParentException("ViewSurrogate must be a direct child of an ancestor of the target view.")
        }
        return TargetViewOffset(viewX.toInt(), viewY.toInt())
    }

    private fun setDimensionsFromTarget(targetView: View) {
        if (width == targetView.width && height == targetView.height) return
        setMeasuredDimension(targetView.width, targetView.height)
    }

    private data class TargetViewOffset(val x: Int, val y: Int)
    private class WrongParentException(msg: String) : Exception(msg)
    private class InvalidTarget(msg: String) : Exception(msg)
}
```

Add the following to the layout and constrain the button to the top and bottom of this view:

```
<[your package name].ViewSurrogate
    android:id="@+id/surrogateView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:drawOutline="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:targetView="@id/chat_text"
    tools:layout_marginTop="359dp" />
```

`drawOutline` is a boolean that determines whether the outline of the view is drawn to aid in debugging.

`targetView` is the id of the view to replicate. Here it is the *TextInputEditText*.

Positioning of the surrogate view will be accomplished by setting the top and left margins of the surrogate view, so we constrain the view to the top and left of the parent.

The layout editor doesn't completely replicate the Android system's layout processing, so the `tools:layout_marginTop` is needed to approximate the location of the surrogate view in the Android Studio designer.  We would also need to do this if the position of the button were hard-coded in our app.

Here are the styleable definitions:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ViewSurrogate">
        <attr name="drawOutline" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="targetView" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here is the layout as it appears in an emulator. The red outline shows the extent of the surrogate view.  Notice how the button is centered on the *TextInputEditText*. (The red outline shows the extent of the surrogate view.)

[image]

If we want the button to appear to extend to the top and bottom of the *TextInputEditText* we would need to set the top and bottom insets to `0dp`.

```
android:insetTop="0dp"  
android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

So, it will now look like this:

[image]

I think that this could be a general solution to reach inside any *ViewGroup* embedded within a *ConstraintLayout* to pull out a view for the purpose of applying constraints.

*(Lightly tested with ConstraintLayout 2.0.4)*

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` for your `EditText`. Which prevents you to type multiline.

If you do not want to type multiline in your `EditText` then there won't be any chance for the height of the `Button` to grow. In this case you can align your `Button` with the `EditText`.

For that here is the XML code for your `Button`.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chat_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chat_text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />
```

If you want to type multiline in the `EditText` then yes, you can have your `Button`'s height grow with the `EditText` keeping the `Button` aligned with the `EditText`.

For that, first you need to remove `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` from `EditText`.

Then use the following XML.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/finish_panel">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:id="@+id/chat_text_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/chat_send_button"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_clear"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="200"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint="Chat">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/chat_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxHeight="200dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/chat_text_container"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:iconPadding="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have used `android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"` for the `Button` so that it offsets the height of the counter text. That worked perfectly fine for my two emulators with landscape and portrait orientation. If you want you can adjust that as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really appreciate your detailed suggestion. However, the question is not about solving a multiline-editText problem. My goal is to make the button "follow" the TextInputEditText (which is a nested view). What I mean by "follow" is that they should have the same middle, no matter how their heights are (and then preferably, having their tops aligned, and their bottoms aligned)

Comment: For that my second approach should work. I have made change to your code. So, just copying my code and replacing your code should work. Did you try to see how it looked like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want button height as per TextInputEditText The only solution is to set button height dynamically and button text gravity will be centre. Because you can not constraint your child view with the parent container.
Also, If you want to change button height as per increase edit text height then also change the button's height in text change listener.